# Should the English word for noodles be ''lamen'' or ''ramen''?

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, loanwords

The Chinese word for noodles is *lamen*, or *la-mien*, and the Japanese also call it *lamen*, using their hiragana/katana syllaby. So the word is spoken with the *L* sound in both China and Japan (Taiwan, too), not the *R* sound.

However, modern English spells it and speaks it as *ramen* and I wonder:  was this an editing/spelling mistake made by Japanese or English editors in the 1950s? Ask any Japanese person in Japan and they will tell you it's really *lamen*. Why did English-speaking countries turn it into *ramen* and is there any way to turn it back to its correct spelling and pronunciation: *lamen*?

Comment: Actually, the more proper phonetic translation requires a letter with the sounds L and R combined. So neither translations are incorrect; rather, it depends on how you look at it.

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog: how to write that combo letter? Good idea!

Comment: But Sonic, the words for London, Lover, locksmith and Louisiana in Japanese are all written with that so-called L/R combo character, if you will, but the Japanese do spell those words in English, as we do also, with an L as the first letter, not an R. We don't say or spell it as rover or Rondon, do we? So why did LAMEN gets mis-spelled into "ramen"? All other L/R problems in Japanese are resolved in English into the L letter. Only lamen gets the R treatment? Why?

Comment: Interestingly, there was once a letter that represented the "th" sound, such as the word the. It looked like this: "þ", and whenever a word required a "th" sound, they would use this letter.

Comment: I honestly have no idea; although ramen sounds better than lamen.

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog The Japanese L/R sounds more like a rolled R than an LR combo

Comment: @DanielHaleviBloom I don't think you can say its *incorrect*, considering Japanese has no L sound in the first place. English likely took the sounds they heard, transliterated into the closest English phonetic equivalent, and came up with the unrolled R "ramen"

Comment: @Sim Sorry if I am wrong; I am basing off the L/R problem with Korean Language; we eat ramens too ;)

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog If I'm not mistaken, Korean has both L and R like sounds, while Japanese combines the two into a rolled R (which, without looking, could actually be linguistically classified between L and R). I could be wrong though. Always a possibility

Comment: @sim :O Wait, do we? Last time I checked we didn't... let me check it again. Edit: We do not have R sound, however neither do we have exact L sound either. More like those two combined.

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog Maybe its just transliterated as L (ex Hanwool) but its still the "between" sound

Comment: @Sim yes, more like that. On the further note, we should probably stop commenting; system is giving me warning.

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog . re ''I honestly have no idea; although ramen sounds better than lamen.'' LOL. But don't tell that to the Chinese or Taiwanese who love saying it the ''correct way'' [scare quote alert], as LAMEN. Beauty is in the ear of the hearer!

Comment: @simchona, re ''I don't think you can say its incorrect, considering Japanese has no L sound in the first place.'' Yes? Then how do the Japanese newspapers in Tokyo, the English newspapers there, run by Japanese people who are bilingual, how do they write words like London or Louisiana or lover or Maryland when they write articles in English? They use an L, sir. They not do call London as Rondon, do they? So why did they change the perfectly lovely LAMEN to the ugly RAMEN?

Comment: In fact, there is a "ramen" lestaurant in NYC and it's sign out front and on the Internet says "Tokyo Lamen". That is the only lamen restaurant in the USA that spells the original Chinese word [that the Japanese borrowed as a loan word] correctly. Google it and see.

Comment: BTW, I lived in Japan for 5 years, worked an English newspaper in Tokyo, copy desk, speak Japanese, and I always used to say RAMEN. Until I came to Taiwan to work for newspapers here and realized that in fact the word is a Chinese word, la-mien or lamen, and that in fact it begins with an L sound. Things you learn when you travel overseas!

Comment: and the man who gave the world INSTaNT RAMEN was in fact, not a Japanese man, he was a Taiwanese immigrant to Japan, who later took a Japanese name, Ando Momoko or something but his real name was Mr Wu in Taiwan, and his relatives still live in Taiwan. He converted to Japanese citizenship yes, but he was always an ethnic Chinese man, something the Japanese do not like to admit. And yes, this Taiwanese man who started the CUP NOODLES craze, he called his product RAMEN, but he shoulda known better. It's really LAMEN. Get used it. unless you like LAMBURGERS better.

Comment: Get used to it? English isn't suddenly going to adopt lamen because you say so

Comment: simchona, no it won't happen overnight. But it will happen. RAMEN is simply wrong in English. Even the NYTimes food writer agrees with me. But he is afraid to say this in public. It's a small minor issue, for sure, but I like to sink my teeth into small minor issues and change the tide of thinking. I used to be on the side of RAMEN, then I came to China and Taiwan and realized it's not even a Japanese word. And that the word was transposed into English in an incorrect way. Probably by a Rondon Lewspaper editor.

Comment: The informational content of this question an answers is excellent. The tendentious attitude distracts from the good story, but adds an instance to the meta-story of descriptivism vs prescriptivism -and- language change and borrowings. Exec Summary: What should be and what is aren't the same...or shouldn't be...or something. I think you might have picked that up from the responses, comments, and closing.

Comment: @DanielHaleviBloom Next you'll be telling me pineapple is wrong in English because every other country pronounces it ananas. This is not how pronunciation works.

Comment: I see no reason whatever to close this Q. At least it's more 'constructive' than heaps of other questions around here. If anyone makes an effort, it may still be possible to find "what really happened" (euphemism: etymology) behind the spelling. There's already a brilliant point made in the comments that no one seems to care to notice.

Answer (score 13):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, English gets *ramen* from Japanese—not Chinese. They note:

> **Etymology:**  < Japanese *rāmen* (1930 or earlier) < Chinese *lāmiàn* hand-pulled wheat-flour noodles < *lā* pull, stretch, lengthen + *miàn* noodle (see mien n.<sup>2</sup>), with *miàn* assimilated to Japanese *men* noodle (1566 or earlier; < the base of Chinese *miàn*).

There is no character for *L* in Japanese, so both *L* and *R* sounds are written with the same r-based characters. In pronunciation, the sound is [somewhere in between](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_speakers_learning_r_and_l) an English version of those two sounds. However, given that the word is written *ramen* in Japanese, I would guess that either a literal transliteration was made in which the word was copied over as "ramen", or perhaps someone heard it and wrote it down that way.

Either way, it is not "incorrect" to spell *ramen* as such in English. Words go through a process of change as they are borrowed from one language to another, and many other words have changed over time. There are [many other](http://www.ruf.rice.edu/~kemmer/Words04/structure/borrowed.html) borrowed words which have gone through their own changes. The process of adopting a foreign word means it takes on a new life—it doesn't necessarily stay the same as its originating language.

Comment: Unrelated; however I was taught that Japan invented ramen first because of recurring famine. Is this correct?

Comment: @SonicTheHedgehog I'm not sure, to be honest. I'll get back to you about that in chat

Comment: Sonic, wrong. A Taiwanese immigrant to Japan invented ramen. No famine. Just a brilliant idea to make money. And despite what the OED says, the word is LAMEN. Show me one other word in English that was changed like this; re  ''There are many other borrowed words which have gone through their own changes. The process of adopting a foreign word means it takes on a new life--it doesn't necessarily stay the same as its originating language.'' EXAMPLES?

Comment: These Japanese words in English are correct. RAMEN is incorrect. Trust me. re: geisha, hara kiri [not HALA KIRI?], judo, jujitsu, kamikaze, karaoke [not KALA-OKAY?], kimono, samurai [not SAMULAI?], soy, sumo, sushi, tsunami. I rust my case.

Comment: "joy" from French has a completely different sound than its original.

Comment: If you're just going to say I'm wrong, why bother asking the question at all?

Comment: Yes, re "According to the Oxford English Dictionary, English gets ramen from Japanese--not Chinese." BUT the Japanese got the word from the Chinese language and they wrote it down the best way they could in the hiragana/katakana syllaby which has a character that is neither R nor L, and in fact the Japanese speak it as a sound that neither L nor R but somewhere in the middle, true, but in English, the katakana character in every other case is written down in Roman letters as an L. Case closed unless the sushi bar stays open. Oishii!

Comment: You're not willing to entertain any other opinion besides your own, but you are also making an incorrect assertion. "ramune" is on menus both with L and R

Comment: Simchona, I am not talking about French words. I am talking about Japanese to English words.

Comment: These [English words from Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_English_words_of_Japanese_origin) look like they've changed from the original: tycoon, soy, rickshaw, honcho.

Comment: @DanielHaleviBloom: "Show me one other word in English that was changed like this" - if you're restricted to the 'r/l' problem in general then how do you pronounce 'Colonel'? (the French is more literally pronounced)

Comment: DanielHalevi, the words you quoted - samurai, karaoke, harakiri - prove that R is the conventional way of representing the Japanese r/l consonant in English. "Lamen" would be inconsistent based on the data you yourself pointed out as "correct".

Comment: Actually, thinking about this some more, there's a nice parallel (of a loanword being "incorrectly" influenced by an intermediate language) the other way around: the Japanese name for Mexico is "mekishiko" (メキシコ), imitating the English pronunciation, not the Spanish one (メヒコ, "mehiko").